# Using "$@" inside others quotes in bash

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, quotes

Here is the code of the bash script I want to execute : opening a new console and execute in it clamscan with a list of files

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "clamscan $@"
```

After expansion here what is really executed if the 2 arguments given to the script are
`file1.txt file2.txt`

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'clamscan file1.txt' file2.txt
```

As you see only `clamscan file1.txt` is executed.

If I try another way to write the code

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "clamscan \"$@\""
```

Here is the expansion result

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'clamscan "file1.txt' 'file2.txt"'
```

It doesn't work better.
Does anyone knows how to properly integrate `"$@"` inside others quotes?

**Edit**
My goal is to have after expansion something like

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'clamscan "file1.txt" "file2.txt"'
```

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables, so the expansion result is `gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'echo $@'` and `$@` is not expanded, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Yes, but when `sh` launch command, it will expand the given string. did you try it ?

Comment: Yes I just tried and nothing is displayed. With simple quotes `$@` is not expanded the first time, but expanded the second time with `sh` but treated as an unknown variable.

Comment: No sh do it with or without. did you try : gnome-terminal -x sh -c "echo \$@"

Comment: And why don't you use `$*` instead of `$@`. `$@` is equivalent of `"$1" "$2"` and `$*`is `"$1 $2"`

Comment: `\$@` doesn't work better because `$@` is not a known variable for `sh`.

Comment: I need to use `"$@"` and not `$*` because my arguments are files names which may contain spaces.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the quotes around $@ ?

Comment: `gnome-terminal -x sh -c "clamscan "$@` expands as `gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'clamscan file' 1.txt file2.txt` for arguments `file\ 1.txt file2.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

> 3.4.2 Special Parameters
>   @
>       Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is *equivalent* to "$1" "$2" ….

The important part is *equivalent*, it does *not* expand to `"$1" "$2"`, i.e. with double quotes. If you need that, you have two choices, prepare the parameters yourself

```
for i in "$@"; do
    args="$args \"$i\""
done

gnome-terminal -x clamscan $args
```

or put part of the command line in a script

script.sh:

```
clamscan "$@"
```

and call that

```
gnome-terminal -x script.sh file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Excellent, your for statement is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What if any of the parameters contains quotes?

Comment: @krlmlr I don't really understand the question. Why do you think quotes are special? You can easily test this yourself with a script `for f in "$@"; do echo "$f"; done` and call it with appropriate parameters `sh test.sh 'a"' "'b" c`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: I thought they could mix up something, but apparently it just works :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

params=("$@")

for i in "${params[@]}"
do
    string="${string} \'$i\'"
done;

// subst with your full command, this is only for test purposes
sh -c "echo ${string}"
```

Testing:

```
[root@myhost test]# sh ./script.sh aaaa "bbbb cccc"
'aaaa' 'bbbb cccc'
```

Comment: What if any of the parameters contains a single quote?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable substitutions : `${@/ /\\ }`

Comment: Nice find. It works with the `$*` variable and you need to replace every occurrences of space : `${*// /\\ }`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c `echo "$@"`
```

although I'm not sure I understand what the script is ultimately trying to do (it appears you want to execute one or more files which may contain spaces in their file names).

Comment: My bad. I simplified the exemple thinking it will be clearer. Here is the original code `gnome-terminal -x sh -c "clamscan -r $@ | less"` I want to give to `clamscan` (or whatever binary) a list of files names, each surrounded by quotes because they may contain spaces. Your solution doesn't fit my need.